# Run nested local bash functions via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, function

I have a script like this that declares many functions which use another functions, etc.:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function a {
    ...
}

function b {
    ...
    a
    ...
}

...
```

And another script that uses few functions from that script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

do_something

source "/path/to/functional/script"

ssh user@host "$(typeset -f f_from_that_script); f_from_that_script"
...
```

The problem that it says `environment: line N: another_f_from_that_script: command not found`, that means that the first function uses the second one internally:

```bash
function f_from_that_script {
    ...
    another_f_from_that_script
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to define all those function to be able to run them via ssh?

Answer (score 1):

No, the parser in bash is not able to do a syntax analysis this deep (and it might generally not be possible, since the names of called functions might be computed at run time). To the best of my knowledge, there is no third-party Parser that could do that, but papers describing why it is even theoretically impossible to do in all cases. I have written an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749476/how-we-can-recursively-expand-inline-functions-and-aliases-inside-function/749488#749488) about that.

Instead of forwarding a single function, I'd recommend you run the full script containing all the functions. You could either do that by scp'ing a script to a temporary location and then `source`ing it via ssh, or by just piping the whole script into stdin through ssh.

If you're having to execute complex functionality over ssh regularly, maybe a more mighty, formalized remote administration tool like `ansible` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass *all* the known function definitions to the remote shell:

```
#! /bin/bash -

do_something

source "/path/to/functional/script" || exit

{
  typeset -f # output all function definitions
  echo f_from_that_script
} | ssh user@host bash
```

Note that `sshd` on `host` would run `user`'s login shell to interpret the command that you pass, which would not necessarily be bash (who would use `bash` as their login shell in this day and age?).

Also beware that `bash`'s syntax is dependant on:

- the locale (particularly the `LC_CTYPE` category: charset and character classification)
- the set of options (like `extglob`) being enabled.
- the version of bash

So beware of potential problems if the locale and version of bash is different between the local and remote host or you change some of options from the default.

Answer (score -2):

you can manually load the functions by:

```
. /path/to/functional/script
```

Then it will load that script into the current environment, then the second script can access those functions.

To automate it, simple add at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc

```
. /path/to/functional/script
```

that should fix your issue.

I must be misunderstanding the issue or the error is in ssh command.

Here is my test:

File: function_source.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function testcall {

echo "now here I am"

}
```

file do_something.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./function_source.sh

echo -e "This is called from within the script:\r\n"
testcall
echo -e "End Script - Any further output is from the function call:\r\n\r\n"
```

Script file do_something.sh loads the source file of function_source.sh and then calls the function testcall, that is in function_source.sh.

```
ssh %server% "./do_something.sh; testcall"
```

Output:

> -ssh %server% "./do_something.sh; testcall"
>
> This is called from within the script:
>
> now here I am
>
> End Script - Any further output is from the function
> call:
>
> bash: line 1: testcall: command not found

Now if I reference function_source.sh is .bashrc with the below line added to the end of .bashrc:

```
. ./function_source.sh
```

Now I run the same command:

```
ssh %server% "./do_something.sh; testcall"
```

and the output is:

> -ssh %server% "./do_something.sh; testcall"
>
> This is called from within the script:
>
> now here I am
>
> End Script - Any further output is from the function call:
>
> now here I am

The only way referencing the file in .bashrc does not work is if you have the below in your .bashrc:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

If you do have that code in your .bashrc, then when you run a command using ssh, it will not load your .bashrc enviroment, and therefore will not load your source file.

Note:  This is why you do not just use standard bashrc and script file, you either write them from scratch yourself, or you read every line and know what ever line does.

To cover off the other setups, loading the source file first, then calling the function - Note: I have removed the reference to the source in bashrc:

command:

```
ssh %server% ". ~/function_source.sh; testcall"
```

Output:

> -ssh %server% ". ~/function_source.sh; testcall"
>
> now here I am

and finally, loading the source file in bashrc, and just calling the function using ssh.

command:

```
ssh %server% "testcall"
```

Output:

> -ssh %server% "testcall"
>
> now here I am

Let me know if you need any more examples.

Note: I used a windows Command Prompt, with a modified Prompt of -, to run the ssh commands, the %server% variable was used for privacy reasons, and ssh keys were used to authenticate.

To ensure I cover off on everything, I moved to a ssh in one of my linux vm's, so I can ssh to localhost as terdon suggested.

I also modified function source:

```
-cat function_source.sh
#!/bin/bash

function testcall {

echo -e "now here I am\r\n\r\n"
testanother
}

function testanother {
        echo -e "this is another function\r\n\r\n"
}
```

If I run the command:

```
ssh localhost "$(typeset -f testcall); testcall"
```

output:

> -ssh localhost "$(typeset -f testcall); testcall"
>
> now here I am

However, if I run the command:

```
ssh localhost "$(cat function_source.sh); testcall"
```

Output:

> -ssh localhost "$(cat function_source.sh); testcall"
>
> now here I am
>
> this is another function

You would only need to do this, if you did not have write access to the server you were ssh to, and needed to load the functions into the environment each time.

Comment: The `source` command in the OP's script is an alias for `.` in bash, so the OP is already doing exactly what you say.

Comment: I didnt say to use the source command inside the script.  When you load source inside the script, you are adding the function script to the shell instance that the script is running in, if you run another command, that opens a new instance of bash, the functions will not be loaded in that environment, because that instance is not a child of the instance the script is running in.

Comment: What I suggested, was to load the source file, either in bashrc or load it into the environment from the cmd line before running the script.  Therefore when a new cmd is run, the parent of that instance will have the functions loaded in its environment, and therefore will be able to use those functions.

Comment: I suggest to the two down voters, that you create this example in a test environment, and then review your down vote accordingly

Comment: Yes, which is precisely what the OP is doing and it fails because they need to run on a remote environment and have nested functions. We have done this in a test environment, may I suggest that you try it too? Your answer is exactly what the OP is already doing: they are sourcing the file with the functions in the script before launching the `ssh` command, so the parent process of the `ssh` command has the functions defined.

Comment: Remember that scripts run in their own subshell. Sourcing a file in a script means sourcing it into the subshell the script is running in. Actually, sourcing _before_ you run the script wouldn't work unless you also run `export -f function_name`. In any case, just try it and you'll see that it fails. You can `ssh localhost` to test it.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the issue, do you not have write access to the "remote" server,  The source file is on the local machine, and you want to run those functions on the remote machine, and enable the functions from the source file, to call other functions in that file?

If that is the situation, then I covered that off in the last examples I have added.  However, I suspect, if you dont have write access to the remote machine to store the source file, or you are not wanting to store it on the remote machine, then I suspect you are doing something you are not authorised to do.

Comment: Ah yes, the last example, with `$(cat file)`, would work as long as _everything_ in the functions file is a function and no commands are run by mistake.  Thanks! I would remove the rest of the answer to be honest, since the first part is still suggesting what the OP is already doing.  And yes, the idea is that you have all the files and code on the local machine and are trying to execute it on the remote. This isn't only useful when you don't have write access to the remote, but also when you need to do this to multiple machines and don't want to have to edit remote files on every one.